# python subprocess: how to run an app on OS X?

Tags: python, macos, osx-snow-leopard, subprocess

I am porting a windows application to OS X 10.6.8. It is a new platform for me and I am facing some difficulties.

The application is a small webserver (bottle+waitress) which is starting a browser (based on chromium embedded framework) thanks to a subprocess call.

The browser is an app file and runs ok when started from gui.

I am launching it this way:

```
subprocess.Popen([os.getcwd()+"/cef/cefclient.app", '--url=http://127.0.0.1:8100'])
```

Unfortunately, this fails with `OSError: permission denied`.

I tried to run the script with a `sudo` with similar result.

I can launch the app from shell with the following command:

```
open -a "cef/cefclient.app" --args --url-http://127.0.0.1:8100
```

But

```
subprocess.Popen(['open', '-a', os.getcwd()+'/cef/cefclient.app', '--args', '--url-http://127.0.0.1:8100'])
```

fails with the following error

```
FSPathMakeRef(/Users/.../cefclient.app) failed with error -43.
```

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: `os.getcwd()+'cef/cefclient.app'` doesn't look right. For me, `getcwd()` does not add a trailing slash. You might have better luck with `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'cef/cefclient.app')`

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you need the -a after the open? I believe you only want that if you are attempting to "open" a document and need to provide the name of the application with which to open said document with.

Comment: Right the / is missing after getcwd. Anyway, the command still fails

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file `cefclient.app` is actually a directory (an [application bundle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_bundle), specifically), not the application executable.  The real executable is located inside the bundle, with a path like `Contents/MacOS/executable_name`.  So to launch it, you'd do this:

```
subprocess.Popen([os.getcwd()+"/cef/cefclient.app/Content/MacOS/executable_name",
                  "--url=http://127.0.0.1:8100"])
```

Comment: Using `open -a "Application Path" [arguments to app]` should work, though. E.g. `open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app http://www.google.com` opens Google in my Chrome session. Your solution will start another instance of the app -- which is something you'd generally not do on OS X.

Comment: So it should be `Popen(['open','-a','cef/cefclient.app','--args','--url-http://127.0.0.1:8100'])` ?

Comment: Yes, that seems to work for me. `subprocess.Popen(['open', '-a', "/Applications/Google Chrome.app"])` works for me (above, http://google.com was the "file" that open was told to open with Google Chrome, not an argument passed to Chrome)

Comment: This works, but If I use the "open" command (necessary to launch Mac OS-X code bundles such as .app applications - the subprocess is of the "open" process, not the actual App I was launching. Any way to grab the subprocess of the real application I want to launch?

Comment: It works, but... First, the Popen object represents the 'open' process, not the Chrome.app, Second - the 'open' is very short-lived, and so you don't get hold of the actual App - in case you want to capture its input/output, communicate with it, or even kill it. So, this solution is far from perfect;

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively,

```
os.system('open -a "cef/cefclient.app" --args --url-http://127.0.0.1:8100')
```

Just depends if you want to control stdin / stdout or if starting the app is enough.