# File dialog in Mac to find app

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I have some Python code which works well in Windows and Ubuntu Linux, but has a problem on Mac.

What I am doing is presenting a user (within my app) the ability to choose an application he wants opened whenever he presses a button on my app (so that he can invoke without having to search for it every time)

The setup code goes like this (simplified):

```
self.app_opt = options = {}
options['title'] = 'Please choose an app from your computer'
options['initialdir'] = '~/'
chosen_app = "~/"
chosen_app = askopenfilename(parent = self.parent, **self.app_opt)
self.chosen_app = chosen_app
```

Later on, the button is pressed and the code in the button looks like this:

```
subprocess.Popen(self.chosen_app)
```

As I said, it works fine in Windows (I go over to "Program Files", select an executable and all is fine), it runs when I push the button. Also in Ubuntu - (I select from say /usr/bin) and app runs fine when I push the button.

Tried to do this in Mac - just as an example we would like to open iTunes when pressing the button - Now the real app to run iTunes is found at e.g.

> /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunes

But I can't select deeper than

> /Applications/iTunes.app

Is there some option/setting I need to put in the file dialog to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking a friend (thanks DJ!) It seems I was going about this the wrong way

In Mac I should not be calling

```
subprocess.Popen(self.chosen_app)
```

but something more like

```
subprocess.Popen('open -a \"' + self.chosen_app + '\"')
```

as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072158/python-subprocess-how-to-run-an-app-on-os-x)

Will report back on how this works